# How to inform callers when required rquest parameter is missing?

Tags: spring-mvc

I use spring mvc for my restful http api. Request parameters can be annoted as required by

```
@RequestParam(value = "group", required = true) String someParam
```

When calling the api without the required parameter, some ugly info returns.

```
HTTP/1.1 400 Bad Request
Content-Type: text/html;charset=ISO-8859-1
Cache-Control: must-revalidate,no-cache,no-store
Content-Length: 1380
Server: Jetty(8.1.9.v20130131)

<html>
<head>
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=ISO-8859-1"/>
<title>Error 400 Bad Request</title>
</head>
<body><h2>HTTP ERROR 400</h2>
<p>Problem accessing /api/brokers. Reason:
<pre>Bad Request</pre></p><hr /><i><small>Powered by Jetty://</small></i><br/>
<br/>

</body>
</html>
```

Is is possible to catch these kind of errors so that i can inform the caller what's missing.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to catch [MissingServletRequestParameterException](http://static.springsource.org/autorepo/docs/spring/3.2.0.M1/api/org/springframework/web/bind/MissingServletRequestParameterException.html)

```
@ExceptionHandler(MissingServletRequestParameterException.class)
public String missingParamterHandler(Exception exception) {
  /*inspect and exception and obtain meaningful message*/
  return "default-error-view"; /*view name of your erro jsp*/
}
```

Comment: Thank you @NimChimpsky for this valuable answer ...i solved my problem due to this post after 6 hours research of  MissingServletRequestParameterException while service call in spring @ Responsebody

Answer (score 0):

```
@ResponseBody
    @ExceptionHandler(MissingServletRequestParameterException.class)
    public Object missingParamterHandler(Exception exception) {
        // exception handle while specified arguments are not available requested service only. it handle when request is as api json service       
        return  new HashMap() {{ put("result", "failed"); put("type", "required_parameter_missing");}};
    }
```